# How to copy js to html file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, webpack

I want to render html file with css, fonts and js inside (not linked but content inside). Css and fonts I have, but I can't find solution for js. I work on Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [html-webpack-inline-source-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin).

Add to the `plugins` object in your `webpack.config.js` file

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' // embed all javascript and css inline
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
]
```

**NB** : This plugin only works together with [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

you can use code block.

```
<code>js code here</code>
```

It is non executable code.

Comment: Probably misunderstanding, I need paste compiled js to rendered html by webpack.